# adding if/else statement to jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add an if statement to the code on the bottom, I was able to add console.log and it worked but need to have it where it goes something like "if(something).onClick open this page" please help.

```
$.myFunc = function(){
    console.log("clicked");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) It's not at all clear what you're asking here, what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking about on click event? For example user click on button you want to perform an action?

You need to give id or class to that element and using jQuery you can listen to the onClick event when it gets triggered.

```
$("#button").click(function(){
//your code here
});
```

No need to put if condition in function.
P.s - Use # for id and . for class.

Comment: the main thing i want to achieve is maybe a small window pops out of the calendar i have made when clicked on a date to show a comment box. Thats what i thought I could use the on click function. So I put ur code above and under it I would still need a way to tell it where to go, which is most likely either going to be a bootstrap module drop down menu or another page with the comment box already peaking out of the side of the calendar

Comment: You need to show your code and expected output.

Comment: I ended up using the window.location option, thanks again for your help, smit.

Comment: Welcome. If the answer has solved your primary issue please mark it as accepted. Thanks @BernesSuljic